# Class instance assistance

Tags: java, object, constructor, instance

I am working on a program that is supposed to implement an electronic store. I had to create 3 classes (desktop, laptop and fridge) with specific defined functionality which I did. I am stuck on how to create the Electronic store class in which the constructor for this class
must create three instances of each of the previous three classes (9 items in total, using the
constructors defined in those classes) and store them within the ElectronicStore instance being created. I am unsure on how to do the above and would appreciate assistance. Below is what I have gotten so far.

```
// Desktop class
public class Desktop{
  double speed = 0;
  int ram, storage = 0;
  boolean storageType;

  public Desktop(double s, int r, int p, boolean t){
    speed = s;
    ram = r;
    storage = p;
    storageType = false;
  }

  // This is a String representation of the Desktop object
  //@Override 
  public String toString(){
    return "#"+speed+"#"+ram+"#"+storage;
  }
}

// Laptop class  
public class Laptop{
  double CPU;
  int RAM, storage, size;
  boolean storeType;

  public Laptop(double C, int R, int st, int si){
    CPU = C;
    RAM = R;
    storage = st;
    size = si;
    storeType = false;
  }

    // This is a String representation of the Desktop object
    public String toString(){
      return "#"+CPU+"#"+RAM+"#"+storage+"#"+size;
    }
  }

// Fridge class
public class Fridge{
  double fridge;
  boolean freezer;
  String color;

  public String toString(){
    return "#"+fridge+"#"+color;

  }

}
// ElectronicStore class (which i am stuck with)
public class ElectronicStore{
  public ElectronicStore()
  {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You create an instance of a class like so:

```
Desktop desktopOne = new Desktop(x, y, z);
```

To store them you can either have class variables (like you have for speed, ram) etc., or you could use a data structure like a list. Further clarification needed on that point.

Comment: the specifications of the task said the following:
 For storage purposes in the ElectronicStore class, you can use one or more arrays or
lists (your design choice) to store the products. You can hard-code the argument values for the
product constructors (i.e., CPU speed, RAM, color, etc.) or use a random generator to randomly
assign them.

Comment: Ok, so you can create three lists, one for each class type.

Comment: Ok, that part I get but if you understand what it means, when they say 3 instances of each of the previous 3 classes (9 items total), what exactly does that mean?
I am kind of confused on how to go about it. I am still fairly novice at programming with Java.

Comment: As far as I can tell it means create three instances (i.e. instantiate three "versions") of the classes you created, each. So three desktops, three fridges etc. Then add them to a List (e.g. a list of desktops, a list of fridges).

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be something like this

```
public class ElectronicStore{
  private ArrayList<Fridge> fridges = new ArrayList<>();
  public ElectronicStore()
  {
     Fridge fridge1 = new Fridge();
     Fridge fridge2 = new Fridge();
     Fridge frigde3 = new Fridge();
     fridges.add(fridge1);
     fridges.add(fridge2);
     fridges.add(fridge3);

     ... 
  }
}
```

And you have to do the same thing to create the other objects.

Comment: Hey man, could I contact you privately, I am trying to do the above but I keep getting compilation errors for some reason..